# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The client is closed in NodeJS and Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm implementing `Access Token` and `Refresh Token` using `JWT` for login function in `NodeJS` application. I'm trying to use `Redis` to store the `Refresh Token`, but I'm getting the following code :

#### redis.js

```
const redis = require('redis');

require('dotenv').config({ path : __dirname + '/../config/env/.env' });

let redisClient;

redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1');

module.exports = redisClient;
```

#### authRoute.js

```
'use strict';

const JwtUtil     = require('../../middlewares/jwt-util');
const redisClient = require('../../middlewares/redis');

const authRouter = require('express').Router();

const jwt = new JwtUtil(); 

authRouter.post('/user-token/generate', (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(req.body);

    const refreshToken = jwt.refresh();

    redisClient.set(req.body.id, refreshToken);

    res.status(200).send({
        result : 'success',
        data : {
            accessToken,
            refreshToken
        }
    });
});

module.exports = authRouter;
```

I have printed several logs, but it seems that `redisClient.set(req.body.id, refreshToken);` in `authRoute.js`. There seems to be an error in.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The client is closed
>
> (node:24640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) (node:24640) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

`Access Token` and `Refresh Token` are issued normally. Also, the following code doesn't work. I'm not sure how I should rewrite the code. What should I do?

```
redisClient.on('connection', () => { 
  console.info('Redis connected!');
}
```

Although I'm using the `Windows`, I downloaded `Redis`, performed a `ping` test, and confirmed that the server is running.

Comment: Before `redisClient.set(req.body.id, refreshToken);` you have to use `redisClient.connect();`

Comment: @Mani Thanks :D! It was a really simple matter. It looks like you didn't look a little deeper.

Comment: @MinwooKim did you manage to find the solution? I also encounter this with NextJS.

Comment: @MinwooKim uninstall your redis (npm uninstall redis), reinstall it using the version 3.0.2 (npm install redis@3.0.2). Also use this installer https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/tag/win-3.2.100

Comment: I ran into the same issue and used redis 3.02 (as you suggested) instead of redis 4.0 - and that fixed the error.  Thanks @MinwooKim

Comment: @JuliodeLeon Sorry for the late reply. I solved the problem by keeping the existing `redis` package and performing initialization work through the `connect()` function.

Answer (score 3):

As for now I am able to solve partially to get data, but for set data still not done for redis v4. #redis #v4 # redisv4

```
app.get('/data',(req,res) => {
     // check in redis first
    //console.log(">>>>url",url)
    (async () => {
        const userInput = (req.query.country).trim()
        const url = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&section=0&page=${userInput}`
   
        const client = createClient({
            host:'localhost',
        port:6379});
      
        client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
      
        await client.connect();

        const response = await  client.get(`${userInput}`)
        if(response){
            const output = JSON.parse(response);
            res.send(output)
        }
      })();

})
```

Comment: able to solve in redis 4.6
Refer for the code https://github.com/Aakashdeveloper/Node_mrng_23/blob/master/weatherapp/redisapp.js

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the client needs to be explicitly connected by way of the `connect()` function in order for the commands to be sent to the target Redis node(s):

```
await Redis.connect();
```

Answer (score -1):

I implement connect to redis v6.2 this way in index.js start file.

```
const redis = require('redis');

const redisCache = createClient({
  url: redis://localhost:6379    
});
redisClient.on('connect', () => console.log('Connected to Redis!'));
redisClient.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
redisClient.connect();

module.exports = redisClient;
```